# Cross-platform way to determine maximum UDP datagram size

Tags: python, linux, sockets, udp

I am trying to improve the portability of a Python program that sends UDP datagrams.

On BSD and macOS, it accesses the `net.inet.udp.maxdgram` sysctl to determine the maximum number of bytes it can transmit in one packet. (On my macOS 11.2 system, the value returned 9216.) This sysctl does not exist on Linux.

There is a socket option `SO_SNDBUF` which indicates the size of the send buffer allocated by the kernel. I can check it with:

```py
import socket
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) as s:
    max_dgram = s.getsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_SNDBUF)
```

On macOS, this returns the same value of 9216. On Linux, though, it returns 212992, which seems much too large for a single UDP packet, so I think `SO_SNDBUF` is not the right thing to query.

(Also, the docs of `SO_SNDBUF` say, "This limit is calculated as the doubled ... option value less 32 bytes used for overhead." That would imply the real maximum size is nearly half a megabyte.)

Is there a way to do this cross-platform? Or if not, what is the right way to do it on Linux?

Comment: Note also that certain router/switch may have a packet limit too.
It's possible to make a negotiation sequence at the connection of a new client.The idea is to send packet bigger and bigger and to see when a packet is not received, you have your limit (the test must be done in both direction)

Comment: The maximum IPv4 UDP payload is 65509 bytes (=65535-28), but the practical limit through routers is generally taken as 534 bytes. You should not rely on values larger than this.

Answer (score -1):

SO_SNDBUF is big because of udp can be fragmented.

[image]

Seems 9216 is 2^13 (last fragment offset) + 1024 (safe payload size)

Linux 212992 is /proc/sys/net/core/wmem_max because you can send packets to few or more destinations same time on one socket, but for SOCK_STREAM it doubled 2^13

If client IP-stack supports ICMP use https://stackoverflow.com/a/26524829/2101808 PMTU discovery. Or do it on application layer by sending packets with DF flag.

Comment: `SO_SNDBUF` is big to allow multiple outgoing UDP packets to be pending at the same time. In practice UDP can *not* be fragmented, as loss of a fragment implies loss of the entire datagram.

Comment: @user207421 you right. no retransmission, but fragmentation works in local networks.